# Lower and Upper Bound Integers, Python

Tags: python

I have to write a function that takes a list of integers, an upper bound, and a lower bound and return a list that has only integers from the argument list that are within the upper and lower bounds (inclusive).

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def getMembersInRange(i):
    for i in range(1,5):
        print (i)
    for i in range(6,10):
        print(i)
```

This is what I tried, but it's not giving me the output desired.

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehension will serve your purposes.

```
>>> k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> upper = 7
>>> lower = 3
>>> [i for i in k if lower <= i <= upper]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

PS: please don't use Python keywords for your variable names... it will cause you trouble, guaranteed.

Comment: You can rewrite the condition in the list comprehension using a more readable syntax: `[i for i in k if lower <= i <= upper]`

Comment: @davidedb I had written it the other way because that's not a valid test in most other languages so it might be more confusing for a beginner, but looking back on it, I agree that's the more Pythonic way.  Updated, and thanks.